# How can I make dialog repsond with email?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I am creating a simple FAQ chatbot. When I want to provide an answer containing an email address to the support team, watson excludes half the email address (meaning it excludes "@support.com"). How can I solve this problem?

I have looked at various sites and cannot find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely there is a conflict in your response text [because of special characters](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-overview#dialog-overview-simple-text). The `@` is used to [reference entities](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language#expression-language-shorthand-entities). So when you write

> Please contact us at support@example.com

then it could be that Watson Assistant tries to resolve `@example`. Have you tried escaping the `@` like `\@`?